# PHPUnit - Mocking a Guzzle / S3 Transfer Class Object With Promise Methods

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle, aws-php-sdk

I have a function that looks like:

```
public function downloadProjectFolder($projectId, $taskToken){

    // Download the project directory if it isn't on the server
    if(is_dir('/path/to/folder/') === false){
        $manager = $this->instantiateS3TransferObject($projectId, $taskToken);
        $promise = $manager->promise();
        $promise->wait();
    }
    else{
        return 'Project Folder Already Exists';
    }

}
```

The above method downloads a folder onto my server from AWS S3 if it doesn't already exist on the local machine.  The actual S3 Transfer object (from the AWS PHP SDK V3 library - which in itself is mostly abstracted from Guzzle PHP) is instantiated by the below function:

```
private function instantiateS3TransferObject($projectId, $taskToken){

    $lastDatetime = time();
    return new \Aws\S3\Transfer($this->myS3ClientObject, 's3://mys3bucket/destination/url',
        '/path/to/local/directory/', array(
            'base_dir' => 'destination/url',
            'before' => function()use($projectId, $taskToken, &$lastDatetime){
                $currentDatetime = time();
                if(($currentDatetime - $lastDatetime) >= 30){
                    $postParams = array(
                        'project_id' => $projectId,
                        'task_token' => $taskToken
                    );
                    $this->curl->post($postParams, 'http://url/endpoint');
                    $lastDatetime = $currentDatetime;
                }
            }
        )
    );

}
```

The above essentially starts my folder download and hits an custom endpoint every 30 seconds asynchronously.

How would I mock out the `\Aws\S3\Transfer` object in this case so that it includes the `promise()` method on return and that method in turn returns the `wait()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do about the `time` since it is a native function and cannot be mocked. You can slightly refactor it for the sake of testability to something like:

```
class TimeGetter
{
    public function getTime()
    {
        return time();
    }
}
```

and then use as

```
$currentDatetime = $this->timeGetter->getTime();
// instead of $currentDatetime = time();
```

So you can mock it later, and return whatever time you need to test your functionality.

Neither you can create a mock for `\Aws\S3\Transfer`, since you explicitly create a new instance in `instantiateS3TransferObject`.

For the rest of the code you will need to mock both `Guzzle` and `curl`. The very rough approximation based on the code snippet in the question:

```
// First Guzzle, but order doesn't matter:
$mock = new MockHandler([
    // first expected request
    function($_self, RequestInterface $request, array $options) {
        // assert $request values meet expectations
        // and return response or exception you expect from S3
        return new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar']); 
    },
    // second expected request, if any, is either instance of Response, Exception, or a function which returns one of them
    // third expected request, etc...
]);

$handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
// then pass it to the class under test
// assuming it is public: 
$cut->myS3ClientObject = new Client(['handler' => $handler]);

// Now curl:
$curlMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\whatever\curl\class\you\use')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['post'])
    ->getMock();

$curlMock
    ->expects($this->once()) // twice, exact,  etc ...
    ->method('post')
    ->with(
        $this->equalTo(['project_id' => 'expected_project_id', 'task_token' => 'expected_token' ]),
        $this->equalTo('http://url/endpoint')
    );
//again, assuming it is public
$cut->curl = $curlMock;

// then actually execute the method you are testing:
$cut-> downloadProjectFolder('expected_project_id', 'expected_token');
```

You can read more how to test Guzzle in [official docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/testing.html).